# Problems getting text and images to centre vertically

Tags: html, css

I've read numerous pages both here and online about how to get text and images to centre vertically, but I just don't seem to be able to manage it. Clearly there is something that I am missing, but what?

```css
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #FFF;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #FFF4E3;
}

#serviceList {
  background-color: #FFDEA5;
  border: 2px double white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.serviceContentMode {
  float: left;
  margin: 2px;
  width: 70px;
}

.serviceContentNum {
  float: left;
  margin: 2px;
  font-size: 20pt;
  width: 75px;
}

.serviceContentOp,
.serviceContentDesc {
  font-size: 12pt;
  line-height: 150%;
}

.serviceContentOp {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.serviceContentDesc {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div id="serviceList">
  <h1>Services</h1>
  <h3>The following services operate in Southend-on-sea:</h3>
  <table width="100%" border="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="serviceContentMode"><img alt="Wheelchair-accessible bus" src="http://www.travelinesoutheast.org.uk/se/images/means/WheelchairBus.gif" /></div>
          <div class="serviceContentNum"><span style="vertical-align:middle;">1</div></span>
            <div class="serviceContentOp">Arriva (in Herts and Essex)</div>
            <div class="serviceContentDesc">Southend - Hadleigh - South Benfleet - Thundersley - Rayleigh</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="serviceContentMode"><img alt="Wheelchair-accessible bus" src="http://www.travelinesoutheast.org.uk/se/images/means/WheelchairBus.gif" /></div>
          <div class="serviceContentNum"><span style="vertical-align:middle;">28</div></span>
            <div class="serviceContentOp">First in Essex</div>
            <div class="serviceContentDesc">Southend - Hadleigh - Thundersley - Benfleet - Pitsea - Basildon</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="serviceContentMode"><img alt="Wheelchair-accessible coach" src="http://www.travelinesoutheast.org.uk/se/images/means/Coach.gif">
          </div>
          <div class="serviceContentNum"><span style="vertical-align:middle;">X5</span></div>
          <div class="serviceContentOp">First in Essex</div>
          <div class="serviceContentDesc">Southend - Southend Airport - Rayleigh - Chelmsford - Barnston - Stansted Airport</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
```

I know that the `vertical-align: middle` is currently only applied to the `<span>` on the service number in the HTML file, rather than in the CSS, but I've tried all sorts of different combinations all to no avail.

So what am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: You should fix you html first, it is full of errors

Comment: That's what comes of footling around with stuff to get it to work, cutting things out and pasting it back in again ... although I think "full" of errors is perhaps a bit harsh. It was just three closing tags that I had the wrong way round. Doesn't make a bit of difference to what I'm trying to achieve, however.

Comment: Have you tried common techniques to vertical align items inside a div? It is a question that gets asked [a ton](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8865463/4124802).

Comment: @Django yes! Although I'm quite prepared to believe that I've missed some. I try not to ask questions until I've exhausted everything I can find (or understand, whichever comes first!)

Comment: I see. And I didn't downvote your question or anything, but why are you using table structure at all? If you were just using tables, you could have set `<tr valign="middle">` to vertical-align content in some table cells. If you were just using divs I wouldn't go with the "float" approach, I would go with display:table and display:table-cell; accordingly, or even better display:inline-block; Are you familiar with any of those? In general, don't use float attribute to structure simple scheme as this (you would only run into trouble like this:). I can fetch some code for you if that helps.

Comment: @Django D'oh! That's what happens when you aren't totally confident with what you are doing, and copy what is already out there. Of _course_ I should be using `display: inline-block`. Doing that makes all of my problems go away. I'll post my amended HTML / CSS as a separate answer, but many thanks!

Comment: @StuartR143 Glad it worked out for you :) BTW, you should accept your own answer as the correct one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With many thanks to @Django, the answer was to get rid of the table and to use just DIV with `display: inline-block` elements. The revised HTML/CSS is below.

```css
#serviceList {
    font-family:Arial, Verdana, Geneva, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:0.75em;
    color:#000;
    background-color: #FFDEA5;
    border: 2px double white;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

.service {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    }

.service:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #FFF;
}

.service:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #FFF4E3;
    }

.serviceText, .serviceMode, .serviceNum {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }

.serviceMode {
    margin: 2px;
    width: 70px;
    }

.serviceNum {
    margin:2px;
    font-size:20pt;
    width:75px;
    }

.serviceOp, .serviceDesc { 
    font-size:12pt; 
    line-height:150%; 
    }

.serviceOp {
    font-weight: bold;
    }

.serviceDesc {
    font-style: italic; 
    }
```

```html
<div id="serviceList">
  <h1>Services</h1>
  <h3>The following services operate in Southend-on-sea:</h3>
  <div class="service">
    <div class="serviceMode"><img alt="Wheelchair-accessible bus" src="http://www.travelinesoutheast.org.uk/se/images/means/WheelchairBus.gif"/></div>
    <div class="serviceNum">1</div>
    <div class="serviceText">
      <div class="serviceOp">Arriva (in Herts and Essex)</div>
      <div class="serviceDesc">Southend - Hadleigh - South Benfleet - Thundersley - Rayleigh</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="service">
    <div class="serviceMode"><img alt="Wheelchair-accessible bus" src="http://www.travelinesoutheast.org.uk/se/images/means/WheelchairBus.gif"/></div>
    <div class="serviceNum">28</div>
    <div class="serviceText">
      <div class="serviceOp">First in Essex</div>
      <div class="serviceDesc">Southend - Hadleigh - Thundersley - Benfleet - Pitsea - Basildon</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="service">
    <div class="serviceMode"><img alt="Wheelchair-accessible coach" src="http://www.travelinesoutheast.org.uk/se/images/means/Coach.gif"></div>
    <div class="serviceNum">X5</div>
    <div class="serviceText">
      <div class="serviceOp">First in Essex</div>
      <div class="serviceDesc">Southend - Rayleigh - Chelmsford - Barnston - Stansted Airport</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why have you used div tag inside td.

You have to check the red tags, because are badly closed
[image]

You close first div before span tag

Comment: I didn't have `tr` at all at first, but I couldn't get the coloured ruling to work properly without it. As to why I then continued to use `div` inside `tr`, I confess that was partly because the developer whose code I was partly reusing had done that. Would you have nested / spanning `tr` and `td` then?